# type assert cant be compiled~(like val_a as val_b)

Tags: typescript

My project is set up by react with typescript, generally, it can work normally, but in some detail, it can not work even cant be compiled, what should i need to config with my project?

this is my tsconfig.json

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "paths": {
      "src": ["./src"],
      "root": ["."],
      "utils": ["./src/utils"]
    },
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true 
  },
  "files": [
    "./js_transition.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*",
    "./server/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "build",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and this is my js_transition.d.ts

```
 // External libs

// These will have to remain until we (or someone else) writes
// proper .d.ts definition files for them.
declare var template:any;
// node's typings definitions currently break stuff, use this instead
declare var require:any;
declare var process:any;
declare var __dirname:any;
declare var module:any;
declare var DEBUG:boolean;
declare var window:Window;
declare var ca:any;
declare var __PRELOADED_STATE__:any;

interface System {
  import<T = any>(module: string): Promise<T>
}

declare const System: System
```

and while i do this,

```
 Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (26:12)

  24 |     set(this.props.dispatch);
  25 |     // wx_init();
> 26 |     (window as any).a = 1;
     |             ^
  27 |   }
  28 |   componentWillUnmount() {
  29 |   }
```

it will throwout this error.